# Pytorch - What is the proper way to minimize and maximize the same loss?

Tags: pytorch

I have an objective function where I am looking to maximize a loss *w.r.t* `f1` and `f2`, which are encoders; at the same time minimizing it `w.r.t` to `g`, which is a bijective convolution and X is just an image.

[image]

Here is how I assume it's supposed to be done.

```
obs_ch1, obs_ch23 = self.infomin.split_RGB_into_R_GB(obs=obs_RGB)
obs_ch1, obs_ch23 = self.infomin.R_GB_to_frame_stacked_R_GB(
    obs_R=obs_ch1, obs_GB=obs_ch23)

# minimize wrt g
logits = self.infomin.compute_logits(anchor=obs_ch1, pos=obs_ch23)
loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, labels)

self.infomin_discrim_optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
self.infomin_discrim_optimizer.step()

# maximize wrt f1, f2
logits = self.infomin.compute_logits(
    anchor=obs_ch1.detach(), pos=obs_ch23.detach())
labels = torch.arange(logits.shape[0]).long().to(self.device)
loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, labels)

self.infomin_encoders_optimizer.zero_grad()
(-loss).backward()
self.infomin_encoders_optimizer.step()
```

So I have both `f1` and `f2` using the same optimizer which is `infomin_encoders_optimizer`. I calculate the NCE loss *w.r.t* to just `g` then I detach that tensor and calculate NCE *w.r.t* `f1` and `f2`. I take the opposite of that value and backpropagate them separately. The reason I do it this way is because I can't do them together because they are opposing objective directions. Also have to detach what comes out of `g`, because otherwise, it gives an error about multiple gradient updates to `g`.

How are you supposed to minimize and maximize an objective at the same time *w.r.t* to different parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the proper way of proceeding in order to optimize a min-max objective. You can't solve this kind of problem with a single optimization step simply because both loss functions (for `f1`/`f2` and for `g`) are based on a result computed with `I_NCE`. This means you are *required to* infer twice: first for computing the objective for `g`, then a second time for computing the objective for `f1`/`f2`.

Note this is a very similar procedure if not identical to [training a generative adversarial network](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html#training).